# Filter out Private Builds

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We're upgrading our Xaml builds from TFS 2010 to the vNext build definitions in TFS 2015. As part of this, we have a few processes that monitor the builds. These processes filter out the Private builds (i.e. those running against a shelveset without committing the changes on success).

In the new definitions, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to identify these types of builds. When I look at the Reason on the build, its set to `Manual`, rather than (as I expected) `ValidateShelveset`.

Whats the best way to identify these private builds from the REST api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Vnext build, queue build with a shelveset doesn't recognized as a private build. The build reason is "Manual".

Based on my test, the `sourcebranch` is different with other Manual or BatchedCI builds, So to identify the builds against shelveset, we can check the "`sourceBranch`".

Use the REST API to check the build details (attributes）：eg

```
GET http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC/TFVC-ScrumSample/_apis/build/builds/1027?api-version=2.0
```

You can use below sample code to get the builds, then check the `sourceBranch` to identify the shelveset builds:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;

namespace GetBuilds
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tfsUrl = " http://server:8080/tfs/Collection";
            var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri(tfsUrl), new VssAadCredential());
            var builds = buildClient.GetBuildsAsync("YourProjectName");

            foreach (var build in builds.Result)

            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", build.Definition.Name, build.Id.ToString(), build.Status.ToString(), build.SourceBranch.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For other "**Private**" builds, you can also check the build attributes and find out the different with others, then get them accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much the same conclusion I've reached as well. Since the semi-colon is a reserved character in shelvesets, we can test for the existence of this and identify builds as private that way. It seems like a step backwards to be honest.